# Invalid character value for cast specification on column number

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an access database with `address` attribute as `"Text"` data type. In my java/jdbc code, I'm using resultset to retrieve the address value using `select` query. 
Generally, for sql database, It works with `String address= resultset.getString();` 
but, since it's access db how do I query it?

As, I'm using the `String address= resultset.getString();` statement, I'm getting following exception:

```
Invalid character value for cast specification on column number
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java

Comment: Also don't forget to include the column name or number in getString()

Comment: Good Point! It worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the column name or the index of the column while getting the resultset values.

like,

```
String value= resultset.getString(1); // if the text is in the first column
```